# XStream - different alias for marshal/unmarshal?

Tags: java, xstream

Some old XML still has the canonical class name. The new XML has the simple name.

I want to be able to read both formats but make sure that when I marshal I get the simple names. I have tried using...

```
xstream.alias("package.name.className", Clazz.class);
xstream.alias("className", Clazz.class);
```

the unmarshalling works fine but the marshalling is mixed. For some classes I get the simple name, others the canonical.

Any idea how to achieve this with the same xstream instance?

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful way would be writing a custom Converter for your class.

The other way is have one xstream instance for unmarshalling with both alias and another xstream instance for marshalling only with the alias you want.

Comment: I already have 2 instances hence my question about using 1 instance. I dont like the prospect of custom converter, to much hassle! I was hoping there was some way of making the aliases aware of order.